# How to do multi row selection in a GridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, desktop-application

I am new to C# and visual studio, cannot find any examples on Internet about my question. The question is how to enable multi row selection capabiity in an object of type GridView.

It seems like an easy set to true member variable, but I cannot find the answer.
Your help would be appreciated.

I found my answer:
Thanks to those who read my question and offered their help.  By the way GridView is a control from DevXpress.

moView.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
DataGridView1.MultiSelect = true;
```

Comment: My class is GridView , your answer is for DataGridView

Comment: I found my answer: Thanks to those who read my question and offered their help. GridView.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true

Comment: I am not sure. This project has been started a long time ago. I am thinking Winform.  Is there a way I could tell???

Answer (score 1):

Set MultiSelect = True, remember you need to Ctrl + Click to select multiple rows

Comment: GridView does not have a MultiSelect member.  Please elaborate on what is  the object that has MultiSelect member varibale. Thanks

Comment: I found my answer:
 Thanks to those who read my question and offered their help.

GridView.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true